# key in dictionary written in 3 is str?

Tags: python, dictionary

I make my algorithm that if I insert a number (for example 3) then algorithm shows the name of that number.
I insert 3 though, it printed only '?' it should show the name of students number
what is the problem in my code?

```
    dict={1:'윤성준',2:'김희철',3:'강하늘',4:'강철중'}
    
    def find_name(dict):
        a=int(input('students number'))
        for i in dict:
            if a==i:
                return dict[a]
            else:
                return '?'
```

Output:

```
students number3

    ?
```

Comment: You have a dictionary, just lookup as `my_dict[a]`, not looping

Comment: Do not use `dict` as variable/argument name, you're shadowing built-in names.

Comment: Just use `my_dict.get(i)`. Btw, your code will check and return `"?"` _immediately_ when the condition is not met, instead of `continue`ing to the next iteration.

Comment: Following your if else logic, you'd only need `my_dict.get(i, '?')`

Comment: Your function always returns something at the first loop, so it never tests more than the first key of the dict.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't use `dict` it's a `built-in` name and you shadow it.
Also, the `Get` method ensures that if the key is not found then `?` will be returned

```
dic = {1:'윤성준',2:'김희철',3:'강하늘',4:'강철중'}

def find_name(dic):
    a = int(input('students number'))
    return dic.get(a, '?')

print(find_name(dic))
```

Input(3) / Output:

```
students number3
강하늘
```

Comment: It's a bit better to work with both input and output out of function, not just output.

Comment: @OlvinRoght, I am not sure I understand, do you want me to remove the function declaration?

Comment: It's just a suggestion. I would move `input()` out of function and pass value as argument of function.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Ah I see, it's actually more clean in the way you suggest, I would do that myself, but I am mimicking the asker's writing style, so I'll think I keep it like this for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a lookup `my_dict[a]` without looping:

```
my_dict={1:'윤성준',2:'김희철',3:'강하늘',4:'강철중'}

def find_name(dict):
    a=int(input('students number'))
    return my_dict[a]
           
print(find_name(my_dict))
```

Note that you should not use `dict` as a variable name because it is a builtin keyword. I changed it to my_dict for you

Answer (score 0):

This code almost wokable, yet there are still some improvements:

1. Input is string and keys are numbers, so convert using `int`
2. Use another name than `dict` for a dictionary (it's a reserved keyword)

The dictionary `get(key, value_if_not_found)` method is extremely useful, as you can search the dictionary or return `value_if_not_found` if key not found:

```
students_to_numbers={1:'윤성준',2:'김희철',3:'강하늘',4:'강철중'}

def find_name(dict):
    a=int(input('students number\n'))
    return students_to_numbers.get(a, '?')

print(find_name(dict))
```

Output:

```
students number
3
강하늘
```

```
students number
42
?
```